# How to call another figure by clicking on the current figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to ask for help on creating an interactive plot in python. The first one will be a histogram. And if you click on a particular part, you will jump to another pie chart to disclose more detailed information in the bucket.

For example,

I have a histogram, shown in pic1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(10)
a = np.hstack((rng.normal(size=1000), rng.normal(loc=5, scale=2, 
size=1000)))
plt.hist(a) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

When I click the second bar, I can get the following pie chart.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
recipe = ["375 g flour","75 g sugar","250 g butter","300 g berries"]
data = [float(x.split()[0]) for x in recipe]
ingredients = [x.split()[-1] for x in recipe]

def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals))
    return "{:.1f}%\n({:d} g)".format(pct, absolute)
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, 
data), textprops=dict(color="w"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get the feature I need?

Thanks

Comment: what specifically are you having trouble with? have you attached any callback to the `on_click` events of the artists?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

Comment: I want to add the feature that clicking the second bar of the first plot to call the second plot. Does this make sense?

Comment: the end product makes sense, but it's not clear what your question is. which part of the programming are you having trouble with?

Comment: My trouble is I don't how to link this 2 plot together. It seems like your suggestion of the callback function should be the direction that I need to go.